# Windows Phone 8.1 app won't run in Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am getting this error

```
Package could not be registered.
```

When I try to run my 8.1 Silverlight app in the emulator.

I have no errors in any of the event logs for AppxDeploy either.

This was a 7.1 app I upgraded to 8.0. Then upgraded to 8.1.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (V12) Update 2 RC.

I will be active on this post and will return if more information is needed.

Comment: Have you read this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30ea5d7b-2eeb-40aa-a2e2-38c278b82fab/upgraded-wp8-project-to-wp81-deploy-error?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK

Comment: I looked in some MSDN blogs and I think that you can fix your project by only checking carefully that all the resources present in the manifest are in the project and well check that they have proper Build Action

Comment: Yup, I have the right images. What I did was create a brand new clean 8.1 app, and copied over the assets folder just be sure it's the same.

Comment: did you compare the projects to see if there's any difference in Build Action on resources inside the project?

Comment: I'll check this next, but I've done almost all I can on my end.

Comment: You might be missing the icon image in manifest file.

See here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125072/deploying-universal-application-results-in-package-could-not-be-registered

Comment: Yeah, if you check that thread, you'll see I posted in it. Also, I created a clean WP8.1 app and compared the icon list and the manifest.xml. They were ok. So unless I'm blind, it's not the icons.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It appeared all of a sudden (I had created a custom SplashScreen image), so I reverted to a git commit where everything had been working fine, but the same error occurred. I strongly believe this is not related to a project, but something's broken in VS or the emulators. However, I can still deploy to real devices, but to none of the emulators.

Comment: **Update:** I solved it (not sure how, though). What I did: Using git, I went back ~20 commits in history (hard reset) and, when prompted by VS, clicked "reload everything". Then, I could deploy. After I went back to HEAD in git, everything still worked, so it was definitely not related to my project, but (I guess) some kind of caching in VS.

Comment: **Another Update:** I found out that the problematic value was the attribute `ProductID` of `App` in `WMAppManifest.xml`. I had changed it in order to be able to use in-app products, but after restoring it to its original value, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong Product ID and Publisher ID in the WMAppManifest.xml file for the project.

Use the ones found in your App and Account summary pages in Dev Center, and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, I had to edit mine by hand and the values in Package.appxmanifest didn't match the ones in WMAppManifest.xml

Comment: Nailed it!, awful information by the SDK in this case. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the capabilities in the WMAppManifest.xml? You need to make sure that you update the namespaces in the existing manifest with the update namespace from Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.

Comment: Yes. I think I fixed it, it was a combination of having the wrong GUIDs in one of the 4 or 5 places you put IDs (Product, PhoneID) and having the wrong icons. You can't tell if it is right or wrong until it is in the app store though. This is something they need to fix eventually. There needs to be error checking. If it's broken, it should not pass the Cert Kit or the Marketplace Cert process.