# Deployment error in Windows Phone 8.1 app with capability Shared User Certificates in manifest

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

If i check the capability "Shared Used Certificates" in the Windows Phone 8.1 application manifest i get the following error:

> Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Package could not be registered.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)

Manifest

```
<Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
```

I am trying to deploy to a Nokia Lumia Icon with Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview.

Any idea what i am doing wrong or what prereq is not met?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to deploy my app to the emulator, but not to a real device. I got the same error. I asked my contacts at the Phone Team and they said this is a bug and will be fixed with the post RTM updates. It should definitely be possible to sideload apps using the 'sharedUserCertificates' to real devices for normal app developers.

Getting such an app deployed through the Store may be restricted, though. This scenario is primarily meant for enterprise apps, deployed within enterprises.

I wrote a [blog post](http://leonzandman.com/2014/05/09/problems-sharedusercertificates-capability-windows-phone-8-1-developer-preview/) about this.

Comment: Thanks for the information both here and in the blog post. Nice to know they are working on a fix.

Comment: I could also build my app in the emulator but got error while deploying in the real device.

Answer (score 1):

If I set my phone to install apps to the phone it works just fine.  If I switch it back then I get the error.

It has something to do with SD cards!! Not the SD cards per-se , but the mech The only thing different was I installed a new SD card this weekend to my Lumia 1520 with Developer Unlock.   I am running VS 2013 Update 4 and have a StandAlone Phone application using a Windows 8.1 shared app class.   It was working before and now its not.  same error as MAGNUS

With save apps to SD CARD setting in storage sense set 
If you use verbose build output it eventually says:

> 2>Follow the phone setting 2>Phone setting says apps to be installed
>   to SD card 2>layout root folder:
>   D:\WPSystem\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts

With save apps to PHONE card setting in storage sense
If you use verbose build output it eventually says:

> 2>Follow the phone setting 2>Phone setting says apps to be installed
>   to internal storage 2>layout root folder:
>   C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts

search your Detailed or "verbose" build output for the term "Phone setting says"
That will get you close.    Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that VS 2013 Update 4 causes the error:

> Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Package could not be registered. 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)

My application was deploying to the phone fine before the update, and started failing immediately after the update. Modifying settings:

> Settings/Storage Sense/Store New apps on my: phone

Solved the problem. Thanks Matt for the tip, saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall current application in your phone, and run agian.
For me its solved

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be related to re-use of the same app template on Windows Phone (does not affect Windows desktop apps).  In the Windows Phone section of the solution explorer, find your app manifest file (Package.appxmanifest), and review the following line near the top of the file (#'s in this example are representative, not actual):

`<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ABC" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />`

If you have re-used the same app template, then the PhoneProductId number must be different from one iteration to the next.  I suggest simply iterating the last digit in the string (e.g., change 1 to 2, or 2 to 3, etc....).  Once you make certain all your Windows Phone apps have individualized values in this field, you should be able to deploy them all independently.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a [missing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125072/deploying-universal-application-results-in-package-could-not-be-registered) in the Package.appxmanifest. Check the visual assets tab in this file (VisualElements in XML) to see if there is some logo missing.

Answer (score 0):

I changed package name in Package.appxmanifest file. So I had to Uninstall app and Re Installation helped me.