# Can't deploy app in real device

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to build a universal app for Windows 8.1 platform. The app is successfully being deployed in the emulator (Emulator 8.1 WXGA 4.5 inch) but when I try to deploy it in my real device (Lumia 820) it shows the following error:

`DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Package could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)`

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (version 12, update 4) in Windows 8.1 and WP 8.1 in the phone. I've also registered my phone for development (developer unlocked).

Comment: Is the phone developer unlocked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deployment error in Windows Phone 8.1 app with capability Shared User Certificates in manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307643/deployment-error-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-with-capability-shared-user-certificat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307643/deployment-error-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-with-capability-shared-user-certificat