# Windows phone 8.1 deployment error when trying to use background task with audio and device use trigger

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, background-agents

I'm trying to create a background task that uses the accelerometer to play with the music in the background (pause, play, etc). In the Package.appxmanifest I have a backgroundtask, that reads the accelerometer and in the Package.appxmanifest it has Device use trigger as supported task type. When I try to add Audio as supported task type I get the following error during deployment:

DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Package could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)

I played with it a little bit and it seems I cannot use any other task type with audio, but without audio I could use anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can't have Audio and Device Use in the same background task. You will have to create 2 background tasks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Here's a short discussion about it on the msdn forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/281e70ae-282c-4f01-aed1-eb30c77ce62c/windows-phone-81-deployment-error-when-trying-to-use-background-task-with-audio-and-device-use?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to `upgrade` your WP application and got the error,have a look at the references given below. Maybe you could be missing an element in your `Manifest` file.

[Deploying universal application results in "package could not be registered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125072/)

[Deploy error: Package could not be registered](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da89f2ee-03b6-43ed-aa21-97ef091798c9/deploy-error-package-could-not-be-registered?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK)