# Communicate between two backgroundtasks in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I'm facing a problem with background tasks in Windows Phone 8.1.

I tried to create a new background task with Device User Trigger and Audio, but I got the error saying:

> Package could not be registered.

I saw this:

[Windows phone 8.1 deployment error when trying to use background task with audio and device use trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402238/windows-phone-8-1-deployment-error-when-trying-to-use-background-task-with-audio) in SO

[Windows phone 8.1 deployment error when trying to use background task with audio and device use trigger](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/281e70ae-282c-4f01-aed1-eb30c77ce62c/windows-phone-81-deployment-error-when-trying-to-use-background-task-with-audio-and-device-use?forum=wpdevelop) in the MSFT Forum.

I tried the solution they pointed but without success.

Anyone knows how I can make 2 background tasks communicate?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this:

- in one of the Background Task (the audio one) I created a Timer and checked if a  LocalSettings value was or not true.
- The other Background task was the one responsible to set it to true, so that what I want to do in the audio will happen as soon as I set the value to true.

I know that this is a "strange" way to do it, but it works ;)